# AutoSuggestBox shows up Property name instead of value

Tags: c#, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

On selection of item in AutoSuggestBox instead of the property value it binds to the property.

This is my xaml.

```
<AutoSuggestBox x:Name="txtSearchBox" ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                    PlaceholderText="Search in Distributor" Style="{StaticResource AutoSuggestBoxStyle1}" 
                    Margin="10,25,10,0" DisplayMemberPath="{Binding entityName}" TextMemberPath="{Binding entityName}"
                    BorderBrush="#000000" BorderThickness="2" TextChanged="txtSearchBox_TextChanged" 
                    SuggestionChosen="txtSearchBox_SuggestionChosen">
        <AutoSuggestBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding entityName}"
                               Tag="{Binding entityId}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </AutoSuggestBox.ItemTemplate>
    </AutoSuggestBox>
```

This is the Code Behind

```
     private void txtSearchBox_TextChanged(AutoSuggestBox sender, AutoSuggestBoxTextChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.Reason == AutoSuggestionBoxTextChangeReason.UserInput)
        {
            List<Master_User_Hierarchy_VM> lstUserHierarchy = new List<Master_User_Hierarchy_VM>();

            txtSearchBox.ItemsSource = null;
            foreach (Master_User_Hierarchy_VM obj in lstMaster_UserHierarchy_VM)
            {
                if (sender.Text != "")
                {
                    if (obj.entityName.Contains(sender.Text))
                    {
                        lstUserHierarchy.Add(obj);
                    } 
                }
            }

            txtSearchBox.ItemsSource = lstUserHierarchy;
        }
        else if (args.Reason == AutoSuggestionBoxTextChangeReason.SuggestionChosen)
        {
            //txtSearchBox.Text = txtSearchBox.Items[0].ToString();

        }
    }

    private void txtSearchBox_SuggestionChosen(AutoSuggestBox sender, AutoSuggestBoxSuggestionChosenEventArgs args)
    {
        txtSearchBox.Text = ((Master_User_Hierarchy_VM)args.SelectedItem).entityName;

    }
```

This is when I enter a character

[image]

When I click an Item in this list

[image]

Again I get the selected Item in the suggestions box. When I click it I get the property Name instead of the value

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Use

```
TextMemberPath="entityName"
```

instead of

```
TextMemberPath="{Binding entityName}"
```

Answer (score 6):

The solution is that I used UpdateTextOnSelect="False" & did explicit binding in Code behind.

Comment: This solved the issue I was having where the model names would come up if I used the `tab` button

Answer (score 2):

I did resolve this by following the UWP/Xaml Samples. Here is my implementation.

**Model:**

```
public class Partner : EntityBase
{   //Name
    public string Name { get; set; }
    //Address
    public string Street { get; set; }
    ...
    //It is important to return the formated string
    public string DisplayName { get { return string.Format("{0}", Name); } }
}
```

**XAML:** 
SuggestionChosen event is not needed to implement.

```
<AutoSuggestBox             PlaceholderText="Search"
                            DisplayMemberPath="DisplayName"
                            TextMemberPath="DisplayName"
                            QueryIcon="Find"
                            Width="200"
                            TextChanged="{x:Bind ViewModel.SupplierAutoSuggest_TextChanged}"                                
                             >

                            <!--If you are using a DataTemplate you need to delete the DisplayMemberPath property, if not you will get an unhandled exception-->
                            <!--AutoSuggestBox.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:Partner">
                                    <TextBlock
                                        Text="{Binding Name, Mode=OneWay}"/>

                                </DataTemplate>
                            </!-->


                        </AutoSuggestBox>
```

**TextChanged Event Method (Implemented in the corresponding viewModel Class):**

```
public async void SupplierAutoSuggest_TextChanged(AutoSuggestBox sender, AutoSuggestBoxTextChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        var queryText = sender.Text;

        if(args.Reason == AutoSuggestionBoxTextChangeReason.UserInput)
        {
            if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(queryText))
            {
                //IEnumerable Returned
                var suggestion = await App.Repository.Partners.GetAsync(queryText);

                if (suggestion.Any())
                    sender.ItemsSource = suggestion;     
            }
        }

    }
```

Notice that you can use x:bind for MVVM pattern porpouse

Answer (score 0):

Set `DisplayMemberPath` to `DisplayMemberPath="entityName", no Binding needed.

Comment: Tried it still the same..removed binding in code behind and set the DisplayMemberpath